# Rx.Net - Convert function variable to Observable stream

Tags: c#, rx.net

I have a method that is actually a listener on some queue.  The input to that method is just a .NET class.  My question is how do I convert the input to an observable stream inside that method?

I have the below, but does this create a new observable every time rather than creating the stream (for the command input)

```
public async Task<Unit> MyHandler(MyCommand command,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var qMessage = Observable
            .Create<Guid>(o =>
            {
                o.OnNext(command.EntityId);
                return Disposable.Empty;
            })
            .Synchronize();

        // subscribe to the observable

   }
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just return the `qMessage` instead?

Comment: Because I want to do operations on the qMessage and  hence consider the qMessage(s) as a stream of observable rather than consider the method (MyHandler) being called "x" times